# How do I configure Travis-CI to use the correct time zone for a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

In my application.rb, I have

```
config.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

And this works correctly in development/test, and production servers. However when I push to Travis-CI, it appears to be localized to UTC for example the output of `I18n.l Time.now`.

Is there something different about the Travis-CI ruby/rails environment?

Comment: please show me gem file

Comment: Hi @Jack, which portion would be of interest?

Comment: please show me all of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way I accomplish setting the timezone is in the before_script section of the travis.yml

They give you root access to the VM running your project, so you can simply set the OS timezone that ruby uses:

```
    before_script:
      - echo 'Canada/Pacific' | sudo tee /etc/timezone
      - sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

If you wish, you can also force an update by adding this below:

```
      - sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: note: this won't work if you are using Travis's container infrastructure which restricts sudo access(sudo: false); use @aruizca's solution to export TZ

Comment: I agree. The other answer correct for containers (that infrastructure just didn't exist when I had to solve this problem :).

Answer (score 56):

This worked for me:

```
before_install:
- export TZ=Australia/Canberra
```

to check that is correct you can output the date with this:

```
- date
```

Comment: This is especially useful on the "new" docker instances where sudo and so on is disabled.

Comment: See here for a list of timezone identifiers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: I agree with @JulianKessel, this should be the preferred answer since most should be using the new docker infrastructure.

Comment: This solution also works for Codeship.  Just set a TZ environment variable to whatever timezone you need to from the list of tz database time zones listed above.

Comment: this worked 100% for me, so much better to do it in the before_install section of travis.yml ... thank you so much ;)

Comment: I use travis for iOS development and I have used this and printed the date it works but still in the iPhone simulator the time zone didn't changed I don't know Why??

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it.

On development my time is +10 GMT.

On Travis my time is +11 GMT.

```
before_script:
  - export TZ=Australia/Melbourne
```

I used Time Cop gem to test time depended code. Here is how i changed what the time is set too on Travis.

Here is an example test:

```
require 'spec_helper'
context "during the week after 11:00am for Morning Follow Up Call" do
  before do
    valid_prospect_params["treatment_enquiry_form"]["contact_time"] = "10:00 am"
    freeze_time = Time.local(2015, 11, 18, 11, 01, 0)
    change_time(freeze_time)
    post :create_prospect, valid_prospect_params
    reset_time
  end

  it "creates follow up activities" do
    expect(prospect_followup_activities).to eq(3)
  end

  it "creates follow_up_call for the next day in the morning " do
    expect(first_call.scheduled_for.to_s).to  eq("2015-11-19 10:00:00 +1100")
  end
end
```

Here is is how i changed the time on Travis. I have 2 methods.

```
def change_time(freeze_time)
  if Time.now.strftime("%Z") == "AEDT"
    Timecop.freeze(freeze_time + 1.hours)
  else
    Timecop.freeze(freeze_time)
  end
end

def reset_time
  Timecop.return
end
```