# How do I configure Travis-CI to use the correct time zone for iOS app?

Tags: ios, travis-ci

I use travis for my iOS app tests and I have some tests which depend on time zone and I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052708/3400939) to set a timezone

```
before_install:
  - export TZ=Australia/Canberra
```

It works when I run `- date` but it didn't apply to the iPhone simulator

This is my [travis link](https://travis-ci.org/KosratDAhmad/MuslimData/jobs/439344009)

**[Update]**

I got the answer from this [github issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8419):

```
sudo systemsetup -settimezone America/Los_Angeles
```